# <a> hyperlink with div inside is to large / wide

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, margin

Surrounding a div with 'a' tag gives weird results, it feels the need to make the 'a' tag as wide as possible instead of the child size inside, i read it as something to do with HTML5.

Edge gives more or less the result i'm looking for, but in Chrome for some reason the 'a' tag is the full width of the page.

I would also like to include the div 'margin' within the 'a' tag. so i can't use the 'onclick' method. Can this be achieved without javascript? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/807/7874fp8a/).

```
<a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC;">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px; display:block;"><h2>text</h2></div>
</a>

<a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC;">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px;"><h2>text</h2></div>
</a>

<a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC;">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px; display:inline-block;"><h2>text</h2></div>
</a>

<a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC; display: block;">
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px;"><h2>text</h2></div>
</a>
```

Comment: A tag’s don’t care about the width, the child element i.e. a div will default show display: block. That’s why some of the div’s are full width (and you’re a element moves with them). You could give the a elements a `display: inline-block;` I don’t fully understand, what you want to achieve with the margin on the a tag.

Comment: Thanks @ThijsBouwes you commenting, it is just so there isn't a empty gap between the divs. So if you miss click the div it still takes you to the link. its not such a big of a deal but i found it weird, it slows the page down if i need to javascript every 'a' tag to find the child sizes inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest workaround I find immediately is surrounding the "a" tag with another "div" tag, something like this:

```
<div style="width: 100px">
    <a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC;">
        <div style="background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px;"><h2>text</h2></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

But is there a specific reason why you want the "a" tag to be placed outside the div? A div element is used to enable correct spacing, the "a" tag is in essence only a hyperlink. So logically you would place the "a" tag within a div, leading to something like this:

```
<div style="background-color: #C00; margin: 0px 8px 8px 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  <a href="http://example.com" style="background-color: #CCC; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <h2>text</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

PS: I used inline CSS here as a quick example, but you should never use this. Make use of CSS classes instead. You'll thank me later.

Comment: Thanks @Jenever for commenting, the reason why its outside of the div is that i would like to include the 'margin' to also be a clickable link(that there isn't a empty gap in between). i cant believe there issn't a easy solution, its a mess of divs(not to be rude to you). I tried to give the 'a' tag the same size class as div but that didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/kbte5bhv/1/
It's a little hack to make the "a" tag wider than its parent by setting width and height to > 100%. The div has a red background color, the "a" has an opaque grey background to see what's going on beyond it.

Comment: That is actually a nice work around if you if you make it transparent! i think i can fiddle with all the feedback to find a suitable solution for my code. Thanks.